# Creating an interface to sort 3 arrays of different objects

Tags: c#, sorting, interface

Hi I have 3 objects which all have a date property however they are all named differently, [ObjectA.CreateDate, ObjectB.DateCreated, ObjectC.DateOfCreation]

I would like to merge all the items into one array and then order them all by date. They all inherit from a unique parent class, so I am going to write an interface that they all will use.

I am new to interfaces, what would be the best approach? Can I write inits specifically for each of the different objects?

e.g

```
interface orderdate
    {
    orderdate (objectA x){
    orderdate.date = x.CreateDate
    }
    orderdate (objectB y){
    orderdate.date = y.DateCreated
    }
    orderdate (objectB z){
    orderdate.date = z.DateOfCreation
    }

    void date (){
    return this.date;
    }

}
```

Then am I able to create an array of type orderDate, add all the objects to it and sort them by that inerfaces date property?

Comment: The code you provide doesn't come close to how to define an interface. An interface is without state, so you cannot initialize it. Another class needs to implement your interface and then initialize it as needed.

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do this kind of thing to make a common interface:

```
public interface ISortByDate
{
    DateTime SortByDate { get; }
}

public class ObjectA : ISortByDate
{
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    DateTime ISortByDate.SortByDate { get { return this.CreateDate; } }
}

public class ObjectB : ISortByDate
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    DateTime ISortByDate.SortByDate { get { return this.DateCreated; } }
}

public class ObjectC : ISortByDate
{
    public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }

    DateTime ISortByDate.SortByDate { get { return this.DateOfCreation; } }
}
```

Then you would be able to create a single list to add any of these three types to:

```
var list = new List<ISortByDate>();
```

You can then do all the sorting you like.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to sort.

You can define an interface with a property to sort on. All classes you want to sort on date should use this interface:

```
public interface IOrderDate
{
    DateTime CreateDate { get; }
}
```

ObjA example which implements IOrderDate:

```
public class ObjA : IOrderDate
{
    public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate
    {
        get { return DateOfCreation; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("DateOfCreation: {0}", DateOfCreation);
    }
}
```

ObjB example that also implements IOrderDate:

```
public class ObjB : IOrderDate
{
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate
    {
        get { return CreationDate; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("CreationDate: {0}", CreationDate);
    }
}
```

**Using LINQ**

```
// Create the list.
var list = new List<IOrderDate>();
list.Add(new ObjA() { DateOfCreation = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100)});
list.Add(new ObjB() { CreationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-250) });

// Ascending.
list = list.OrderBy(o => o.CreateDate).ToList();

// Decending
list = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.CreateDate).ToList();
```

**Using IComparer**

The following class will do the sorting for IOrderDate interface:

```
public class OrderDateComparer : IComparer<IOrderDate>
{
    public int Compare(IOrderDate x, IOrderDate y)
    {
        return x.CreateDate.CompareTo(y.CreateDate);
    }
}
```

You can then fill your list and sort:

```
// Create the list.
var list = new List<IOrderDate>();
list.Add(new ObjA() { DateOfCreation = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100)});
list.Add(new ObjB() { CreationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-250) });

// Ascending.
list.Sort(new OrderDateComparer());

// Decending
list.Sort(new OrderDateComparer()); // Redundant here.
list.Reverse();
```